# Which function is invoked once the view has completely finished loading?

Tags: iphone

Which function is invoked once a view (loaded from nib file) has completely finished loading on iPhone?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`-viewDidLoad`

This is different from the Mac OS X world, where `-awakeFromNib` was the place to do it.

see

[is applicationDidFinishLaunching the wrong place for setting an image for an UIImageView?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/707249/is-applicationdidfinishlaunching-the-wrong-place-for-setting-an-image-for-an-uiim/707309#707309)

Comment: viewDidLoad on UIViewController